# How to change the title of a Button in a TableView (Swift)

Tags: swift, swift3, tableview, phone-number

I am trying to make a button when pressed to call a phone number. In the TableView the button's title is supposed to be changed with the contact dictionary I added

Here is the Button:

```
    @IBAction func phoneLabel(sender: UIButton) {

    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel://contacts.phone")!
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
}
```

and this is the tableview where I'm trying to set the button tile to the contact phone numbers

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactCell", for: indexPath) as! customCell
        let contact = contacts.contactWithIndex((indexPath as NSIndexPath).row)
        print(contact)
    cell.phoneLabel.setTitle("\(phone)", for:UIControlState)
   return cell
}
```

There is an error occurring saying that the button has no value of setTitle. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: It's a label not the button

Comment: if you look at the code phoneLabel is the name of the button

Comment: Did you create an IBOutlet for it?  IBAction is only for handling button presses, etc.

Comment: Thanks! that worked

Comment: @DoughnutMan You have a single cell? Why your button connected as an action mode?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a button and not a label (looking at your sender definition), you must specify UIControlState.normal, not UIControlState.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrolstate/1618233-normal

Comment: Also, you probably need to change `"\(phone)"` to `"\(contact.phone)"`.  Or maybe you have a global variable called `phone`, but that doesn't make sense.

Comment: That too, but that wouldn't explain the "no value of setTitle" issue.